# Adding hours variable to date variable in Oracle

Tags: oracle, date

OK all-This may be simple but I can't see to find an answer via Google.
So I have a date value ('01/01/2020') and in another column I have a variable of hours (let's say 5) that needs to be added. SO I would have  01-JAN-20 05:00:00 in the end.

Any suggestions helpful. Thanks-

```
with t1 as (select TO_DATE('01/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') as DT, '5' as HR FROM DUAL)
select t1.* , ???? from t1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply add the correct fraction of a day, given the hour value:

```sql
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE('01/01/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DT, '5' AS HR
    FROM DUAL
),
t2 AS (
    SELECT DT, DT + TO_NUMBER(HR) / 24 AS NEW_DT
    FROM t1
)

SELECT
    TO_CHAR(DT, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS DT,
    TO_CHAR(NEW_DT, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS NEW_DT
FROM t2;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can also use interval clause as follows:

```
with t1 as (select TO_DATE('01/01/2020','DD/MM/YYYY') as DT, '5' as HR FROM DUAL)
select t1.* , 
       t1.dt + hr * interval '1' hour as new_dt -- this is solution   
  from t1;
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip too!